# How to add param values along with variable values in the objective function using PYOMO?

Tags: python, pyomo

I have written a program to maximize the revenue, where there is a facility that contains Solar and Wind power plants. They serve a demand profile. To serve that demand profile they get some revenue based on **PPA(Power Purchasing Agreement)**. There are three components which affect the revenue:

1. Actual Revenue: **Min( Facility Generation(Solar + Wind), Demand Profile) * PPA**
2. Excess Revenue: **(Max(Facility Generation, Demand Profile) - Demand Profile) * 50% of PPA**
3. Shortfall Penalty (If Facility output is less than **90%(DFR)** of Demand profile then this will apply): **(Min(Facility output, DFR * Demand Profile) - Demand Profile * Shortfall Penalty**

**Total Revenue  = Actual Revenue + Excess Revenue - Shortfall Penalty**
The program that I wrote for this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyomo.environ import *

total_instances = 8760
np.random.seed(total_instances)
load_profile = np.random.randint(80, 130, total_instances)
solar_profile = np.random.uniform(0, 0.9, total_instances)
wind_profile = np.random.uniform(0, 0.9, total_instances)
month_idx = pd.date_range('1/1/2023', periods=total_instances, freq='60min').month.tolist()
PPA = 10
shortfall_penalty_rate = 15
excess_rate = 5
DFR = 0.9
solar_capacity = 120
wind_capacity = 130

# Not in Use right now
load_profile_month = list(zip(month_idx, load_profile))
monthly_sum = [0] * 12
for i in range(len(load_profile_month)):
    month_idx, load_value = load_profile_month[i]
    monthly_sum[month_idx - 1] += load_value

model = ConcreteModel()

model.m_index = Set(initialize=list(range(len(load_profile))))

# variable
model.facility_output = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

#  gen variable
model.solar_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.wind_use = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# Load profile
model.load_profile = Param(model.m_index, initialize=load_profile)
model.solar_profile = Param(model.m_index, initialize=solar_profile)
model.wind_profile = Param(model.m_index, initialize=wind_profile)

model.lost_load = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)


# Objective function
def revenue(model):
    actual_revenue = sum(
        min((model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m]), model.load_profile[m]) * PPA
        for m in model.m_index
    )
    excess_revenue = sum(
        (max(model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m], model.load_profile[m]) - model.load_profile[m]) * excess_rate
        for m in model.m_index
    )
    shortfall_penalty = sum(
        (min(model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m], DFR * model.load_profile[m]) - model.load_profile[m] * DFR) * shortfall_penalty_rate
        for m in model.m_index
    )
    total_revenue = actual_revenue + excess_revenue + shortfall_penalty

    return total_revenue


model.obj = Objective(rule=revenue, sense=maximize)


def energy_balance(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] == model.solar_use[m] + model.wind_use[m] + model.lost_load[m]


model.energy_balance = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=energy_balance)


def grid_limit(model, m):
    return model.grid[m] >= model.load_profile[m]


model.grid_limit = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=grid_limit)


def max_solar(model, m):
    eq = model.solar_use[m] <= solar_capacity * model.solar_profile[m]
    return eq


model.max_solar = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_solar)


def max_wind(model, m):
    eq = model.wind_use[m] <= wind_capacity * model.wind_profile[m]
    return eq


model.max_wind = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=max_wind)

Solver = SolverFactory('gurobi')
Solver.options['LogFile'] = "gurobiLog"
# Solver.options['MIPGap'] = 0.0
print('\nConnecting to Gurobi Server...')
results = Solver.solve(model)

if (results.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok):
    if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
        print("\n\n***Optimal solution found***")
        print('obj returned:', round(value(model.obj), 2))
    else:
        print("\n\n***No optimal solution found***")
        if (results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
            print("Infeasible solution")
            exit()
else:
    print("\n\n***Solver terminated abnormally***")
    exit()

grid_use = []
solar = []
wind = []
# e_in = []
# e_out = []
# soc = []
lost_load = []
load = []
for i in range(len(load_profile)):
    grid_use.append(value(model.grid[i]))
    solar.append(value(model.solar_use[i]))
    wind.append(value(model.wind_use[i]))
    lost_load.append(value(model.lost_load[i]))
    load.append(value(model.load_profile[i]))
    # e_in.append(value(model.e_in[i]))
    # e_out.append(value(model.e_out[i]))
    # soc.append(value(model.soc[i]))
pd.DataFrame({
    'Grid': grid_use,
    'Solar': solar,
    'Wind': wind,
    'Shortfall': lost_load,
    'Load Profile': load,
}).to_excel('testing4.xlsx')
```

The error that I am getting is I think because I am using **Load profile** which is **Param** with the **Variables** **Solar and wind**:

```
ValueError: Error retrieving immutable Param value (load_profile[0]):
    The Param value is undefined and no default value is specified.
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for objective obj: ValueError:
    Error retrieving immutable Param value (load_profile[0]):
        The Param value is undefined and no default value is specified.
ERROR: Constructing component 'obj' from data=None failed: ValueError: Error
    retrieving immutable Param value (load_profile[0]):
        The Param value is undefined and no default value is specified.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the data items that you are using to initialize your parameters should be dictionaries (or other data types like panda series) with key:value pairs.  Your parameter is indexed so the data that you are feeding it needs to be keyed by the same values

```
favorability = {'dog': 10, 'cat': 2, 'pig': 4}
random_numbers = { 1: 22.5, 2: 52.9, 3: 4.1}
```

in the model, something like:

```
m.animals = m.Set(initialize=favorability.keys())
m.case = m.Set(initialize=random_numbers.keys())

m.favorability = m.Param(m.animals, initialize=favorability)
m.cost = m.Param(m.case, initialize=random_numbers)
```

Comment: something like this? model.load_data = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, load_profile))

Comment: Yes this actually worked but this is giving this new error: ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for objective obj: TypeError:
    Relational expression used in an unexpected Boolean context.

            The inequality expression:
                126.0  <  solar_use[0] + wind_use[0]
            contains non-constant terms (variables) that were evaluated in an
            unexpected Boolean context at
              File 'C:\Users\nvats\PycharmProjects\RTC\Model_Code\test4.py',
              line 48:
        for m in model.m_index

Comment: Well, you appear to be trying to use `min()` and `max()`.  Those are illegal/non-linear operators.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77921810/workaround-for-pyomo-constraint-that-evaluates-the-max-min-of-an-optimization/77922419#77922419

Comment: You might benefit from an introductory text on linear programming that covers some of these concepts.  ;)

Comment: Hey, I tried to implement this min and max using the example you shared but I am stuck where we try to store the min value in another variable. I initialized binary which can determine which value is smaller but I can't figure out how to use that binary variable to catch the min value. I have posted another question regarding that, please if you can take a look at that.